# Send MySQL Query w/o Form or Page Refresh

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I want to send a MySQL query without a form as it won't be taking user input. I want this to be done without refreshing the page. You can use any JavaScript, PHP or jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a PHP script which runs the query. Make an AJAX request to this URL with JavaScript to run it.

jQuery example:

```
$.get('runquery.php');
```

Comment: I'mm not very good with AJAX... I understand very little about it.

Comment: AJAX is just a process of letting the client, in this example jQuery, communicate to the server, php, without having to reload. So its perfect for what you are wanting to do.

Comment: Your example would this work if "runquery.php" is (Code for connecting to database) mysql_query("UPDATE table WHERE column=value");?

Comment: Yes, assuming you write a working query, that's all runquery.php needs to do.

Comment: The only thing about this since it is get could I add the value at the end like $.get('runquery.php?something='+value); to actually have it query something specific. I don't need user input but the query won't be fixed. So in the php I could right $value = $_GET["something"]; mysql_query etc?

Comment: Alright then. Thank you guys so much. If I have any more questions I will ask.